# Remote machine option missing in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and just created a new .NET Core 3.1 web api project.
I noticed, that an option "use remote machine" is missing from the debug tab of project's properties.
However, when I open my old project, created in older versions of VS using .NET Core 2 (and then migrated to 3.1)   - the option is present.
I've only recently started needing it and this inconsistency is strange to me.
This ticket on Microsoft website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/use-remote-machine-option-in-debug-settings-is-not/757921 suggests  that it should be fixed in the latest version of VS, but I use the latest version and the problem still remains.

Comment: Maybe try to diff the two different .csproj files to find the missing part ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, was my mistake. I needed to explicitly set launch option to executable. Then it becomes available. I should close the question.